# Two pair in hand vs two pair with table cards and one in hand

Tags: rules, odds, hand, reading-hands, rush-poker

So streight to the point on table was (j,j,10,3,a) one had (10,3) second guy (a,6) so who would win?

Comment: whomever has the best 5 cards win aces up in this case.the player with A6 wins because he has aces over jacks. to practice write down the best hands for each player then compare them, a little practice and it will click.

Answer (score 0):

The best combination for you is J,J,10,10,a.
His best combination is J,J,a,a,10.

(J,J,10,10,a) < (J,J,a,a,10)
Double A,A will beat your 10, 10.

Comment: Correct as far as who wins, but not because As > 10s, it wins because As > Js.